# how to copy first line of a file and sort the rest

Tags: debian, bash

I want to take the first line(s) of an input file and copy them to an output file, then sort the remaining lines of the input file and put them in the output file also.

Comment: What does this have to do with Tor?  Are you trying to copy a file to/from a remote site via Tor?

Comment: Nothing! The tags are debian and bash!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Tor (as stated by the OP: https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/20241/#comment21759_20241).